# How to Pass onPress to custom component and get the values back to calling component?

Tags: react-native

I cloned a react-native GitHub source. In that, for login functionality, they are using for two files on for View and one for functionality.

Here is login.js

```
class Login extends Component {

 submitLogin(email, password) {
   alert('clickedLogin');
  }

render() {
return (
  <LoginView onPress={this.submitLogin.bind(this)} 
             onSignupPress={this.displaySignupView.bind(this)}/>
   )
 }
}
```

Here is LoginView.js -> to which the above onPress and onSignupPress are sent and it has form elements here.

```
 class LoginView extends Component {
   state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      isAuthenticating: false,
      error: ''
     }     

  render() {
    return (
     <View>
        <TextInput
          style={[styles.input, styles.whiteFont]}
          placeholder="Email"
          placeholderTextColor="#FFF"
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
          onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}
          value={this.state.email}/>
       <TextInput
          secureTextEntry={true}
          style={[styles.input, styles.whiteFont]}
          placeholder="Password"
          placeholderTextColor="#FFF"
          onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
          value={this.state.password}/>
      <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.signin}
          onPress={this.props.onPress.bind(this, this.state.email, this.state.password)}>
          <Text style={styles.signinText}>Sign In</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>
   )
  }
 }
```

When *login* button is hitting ***submitLogin*** function is getting called an alert is coming but I couldn't find a way to get the entered *email* and *password* in ***LoginView*** input elements to the Login file and alert it in submitLogin.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using bind on this.props.onPress, otherwise it will not reference the original parent function,
What you may want to do to pass the email and password is something like this :

in the LoginView.js :

```
  <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.signin}
      onPress={()=>this.props.onPress(this.state.email,this.state.password)}>

      ...

    </TouchableOpacity>
```

To learn more about how bind works i recommend reading this article :
https://www.codementor.io/niladrisekhardutta/how-to-call-apply-and-bind-in-javascript-8i1jca6jp